# How to query by partitionkey in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, createquery

I have the following TableServiceContext class for books, I want to query the table Books by the partitionKey, please ignore the fact that 
I'm using the partition key as the book name, this is just for my learning sakes

```
   public class BookDataServiceContext: TableServiceContext
        {

            public BookDataServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
                : base(baseAddress, credentials)
            {
            }

            public IQueryable<Book> Books
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.CreateQuery<Book>("Books");
                }
            }

            public void AddMessage(string name, int value)
            {
                this.AddObject("Books", new Book {PartitionKey=name, BookName = name, BookValue = value});
                this.SaveChanges();
            }

            public Book GetBookByPartitionKey(Guid partitionKey)
            {
                var qResult = this.CreateQuery<Book>("Books");
    This doesnt work ---->           // qResult = qResult.Where(e => (e.PartitionKey.CompareTo(partitionKey)==0));

            } 
}
```

I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" on that last line.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qResult` is already assigned a type by the compiler. You're trying to re-assign it to a different type, but that isn't allowed.

Try this

```
var someOtherName = qResult.Where(e => (e.PartitionKey.CompareTo(partitionKey)==0));
```

**Edit:** It looks like your Books property is the wrong type.

```
public DataServiceQuery<Book> Books
{
    get
    {
        return this.CreateQuery<Book>("Books");
    }
}

public Book GetBookByPartitionKey(string partitionKey)
{
    var qResult = Books.Where(e => (e.PartitionKey.CompareTo(partitionKey)==0));
}
```